# How to go through data files with integers and scientific noation using regex?

Tags: python, regex, scientific-notation

The data files which I have look like:

```
Title
10000XX   1.09876543e+02
```

There are many lines in this form with the column 1 values ranging from 1000000-2000099 and with column 2 values ranging from -9000 to 9000 including some values with negative exponents. I am very new to regex so any help would be useful. The rest of my program is written in python so I am using:

```
re.search()
```

Some help with this syntax would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Use the `split()` function. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

Comment: Regex is often used to extract patterns from data. What exactly do you want to extract?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need regular expressions at all for this. In general it's better to use simpler and more direct methods (see deadly's answer) unless regular expressions really are needed.

Answer (score 3):

As Robert says, you can just use the `split()` function.

Assuming the separator is spaces like you have in the question, you can run the code below to give a list of values, then do with that as you will:

```
>>> line = "10000XX   1.09876543e+02"
>>> line.split()
['10000XX', '1.09876543e+02']
```

You can convert the second item to a floating point number with `float()`. e.g. `float('1.09876543e+02')`

Just iterate over your lines and ignore any that don't start with a number.

Regular expressions are a bit more fiddly.